# read more clickable text at the end of textview after 8 lines

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, textview, label

I have problem to add readmore clickable text in textview  at the end of 8 lines.My textview is in custom cell. according text its height changes.
I have set 8 maximum line to `textcontainer`.

I used layout manager for get 8 line end text and replace with read more text. Its working perfect in simulator. When I tested with actual device layout manager and content size not working for as i seen in simulator.

I used below function for get 8-lines text

```
int counter=0;

NSRange replacewordRange =NSMakeRange(0, 0);

[txtView_status.layoutManager enumerateLineFragmentsForGlyphRange:NSMakeRange(0, Str.length) usingBlock:^(CGRect rect, CGRect usedRect, NSTextContainer *textContainer, NSRange glyphRange, BOOL *stop) {

            counter++;

            if (counter==kTotalLineShow &&glyphRange.length>30 )

            {
                replacewordRange.location =glyphRange.location+glyphRange.length-kKeyReadMoreText.length;

                replacewordRange.length=kKeyReadMoreText.length;

            }

            NSLog(@"rect %@ - usedRect %@ - glymph Rangle %lu %lu -",NSStringFromCGRect(rect),NSStringFromCGRect(usedRect),(unsigned long)glyphRange.location,(unsigned long)glyphRange.length);

        }];
```

I want to generate below result:[image][image]

Any suggestion or help for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this : https://cocoapods.org/pods/UIReadMoreLabel ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this code and make changes according to size of your cell/Label.

```
NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: BODY_FONT_COLOR,
                              NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:FontHelvetica size:AppFont16]
                              };
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:ACCIDENT_DETECTION_AUTOMATIC_TEXT attributes:attribs];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                             value:@"Accident detection"
                             range:[[attributedString string] rangeOfString:@"Read More"]];

NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: LINKS_FONT_COLOR,
                                 NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor],
                                 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)};

// assume that textView is a UITextView previously created (either by code or Interface Builder)
self.accidentDetectionText.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes; // customizes the appearance of links
self.accidentDetectionText.attributedText = attributedString;
```